# Count by checking XML child tag

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, xml-parsing

I want to count child elements based on an if condition.

```
 Declare @MainXml XML =
 '<root>
     <Data>
           <a>FAIL</a>
     </Data>
     <Data>
           <a>PASS</a>
     </Data>
     <Data>
           <a>PASS</a>
     </Data>
   <root>'
```

I want to get the amount of "Data" elements where the child element "a"'s value is "FAIL". The above count is 1.

I am storing this count in an SQL column. How can I do this?

Comment: If you really want help, you need to state what you have tried and what was the result of that attempt.  Also, is this for mySQL or SQLServer; you have tagged both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's a more direct way, but you could certainly shred the XML and then count up the results, like this (in SQL Server)

```
Declare @MainXml XML =
'<root>
    <Data>
          <a>FAIL</a>
    </Data>
    <Data>
          <a>PASS</a>
    </Data>
    <Data>
          <a>PASS</a>
    </Data>
  </root>'

select count(1)
from @mainXML.nodes ('root/Data') t(c)
where t.c.value('a[1]', 'char(4)') = 'FAIL'
```